# Transfer aukciono_id from one table to another

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to transfer "aukciono_id" from one table to another. I was trying to do it using a single while loop and maybe it would work but the main problem is when the user **hovers**  over the element class "placiau", another table displays not **hovered** element's "aukciono_id". I just cannot use while loop because while loop iterate through the query one by one. I have to identify every `<td class="placiau"></td>` "aukciono_id" somehow. Also, the table should appear next to the **hovered** element but I will fix it by myself.

---

```
<table>
<?php
$aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while = mysql_query("SELECT taw.id AS taw_id,
    tai.aukciono_id AS tai_aukciono_id, taw.user_id AS taw_user_id, taw.win AS taw_win,
    tai.date AS tai_date, taw.date AS taw_date, COALESCE(SUM(tai.bid), 0) AS tai_bid
FROM tb_auction_winners taw JOIN tb_aukciono_istorija tai
ON taw.id = tai.aukciono_id
WHERE tai.user_id = 206 GROUP BY aukciono_id");

$aukciono_istorija1_while = mysql_query("SELECT tab.id, tu.level, tab.user_id, tab.user,
    tab.bid, tab.date, tab.aukciono_id FROM tb_aukciono_istorija tab JOIN tb_users tu
ON tab.user_id = tu.id
WHERE tab.aukciono_id = 47 ORDER BY tab.id DESC");

while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while)) {
    if ($r1['taw_user_id'] == 206) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r1['taw_date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r1['taw_win'] - $r1['tai_bid']; ?> Eur</td>
            <td>0 Eur</td>
            <td class="placiau">Plačiau <?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    } else { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r1['tai_date']; ?></td>
                <td>0 Eur</td>
                <td><?php echo $r1['tai_bid']; ?> Eur</td>
                <td class="placiau">Plačiau <?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
<table id="aukciono_apzvalga" style="
width: 69.7%;
left: 632px;
position: absolute;
top: 590px;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
display: block;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 480px;">
<?php
    while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija1_while)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r1['aukciono_id']; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<script>
    $('.placiau').hover(function() {
        $('#aukciono_apzvalga').css('opacity', 1);
    }, function() {
        $('#aukciono_apzvalga').css('opacity', 0);
    });
</script>
```

Picture how it looks like:

[image]
**Note: 47 is just a random number as an example how it looks like**

When the user **hovers** "42", for example, it should show 42, instead of 47 in the other table and also in the "$aukciono_istorija1_while" query. Is it possible to do so?

*PS: I know, I should use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*`*

Comment: where is your "on hover" function code?

Comment: @Mohammad updated my question.

Comment: so for each row you want to show different table?

Comment: Yes, according to the aukciono_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! :) It was a bug in the while loop.

```
</table>
<?php
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija1_while)) { ?>
<table class="aukciono_apzvalga" data-aukciono-id="<?php echo $r1['aukciono_id']; ?>" style="
width: 69.7%;
left: 632px;
position: absolute;
top: 590px;
z-index: 1;
opacity: 0;
display: block;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 480px;">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">Aukciono apžvalga</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Nr.</th>
        <th>Žaidėjas</th>
        <th>Lygis</th>
        <th>Suma</th>
        <th>Laikas</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    $i = mysql_num_rows($aukciono_istorija1_while);
    $apa = $r1['aukciono_id'];
    $aukciono_istorija2_while = mysql_query("SELECT tab.id, tu.level, tab.user_id, tab.user, tab.bid, tab.date, tab.aukciono_id FROM tb_aukciono_istorija tab JOIN tb_users tu ON tab.user_id = tu.id
    WHERE aukciono_id = $apa ORDER BY tab.id DESC LIMIT 10");
    while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija2_while)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $r2['aukciono_id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r2['user']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $r2['level']; ?> lvl.</td>
            <td><?php echo $r2['bid']; ?> Eur</td>
            <td><?php echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($r2['date'])); ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
        $i--;
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only one table generated by the loop, you should build all the possible tables inside the loop, and give each table a different id related to the `aukciono_id`, then in the on hover function, get the target `aukciono_id` and show the table related to this id.
try this:

```
<?php

$aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while = mysql_query("SELECT taw.id AS taw_id,
    tai.aukciono_id AS tai_aukciono_id, taw.user_id AS taw_user_id, taw.win AS taw_win,
    tai.date AS tai_date, taw.date AS taw_date, COALESCE(SUM(tai.bid), 0) AS tai_bid
    FROM tb_auction_winners taw JOIN tb_aukciono_istorija tai
    ON taw.id = tai.aukciono_id
    WHERE tai.user_id = 206 GROUP BY aukciono_id");

$aukciono_istorija1_while = mysql_query("SELECT tab.id, tu.level, tab.user_id, tab.user,
    tab.bid, tab.date, tab.aukciono_id FROM tb_aukciono_istorija tab JOIN tb_users tu
    ON tab.user_id = tu.id
    WHERE tab.aukciono_id = 47 ORDER BY tab.id DESC");

?>
<table>
<?php
while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while)) {
    if ($r1['taw_user_id'] == 206) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r1['taw_date']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r1['taw_win'] - $r1['tai_bid']; ?> Eur</td>
        <td>0 Eur</td>
        <td class="placiau" data-aukciono-id="<?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?>">Plačiau <?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r1['tai_date']; ?></td>
        <td>0 Eur</td>
        <td><?php echo $r1['tai_bid']; ?> Eur</td>
        <td class="placiau" data-aukciono-id="<?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?>">Plačiau <?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
<?php
    while ($r1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($aukciono_istorija1_while)) { ?>
<table class="aukciono_apzvalga" data-aukciono-id="<?php echo $r1['aukciono_id']; ?>" style="
    width: 69.7%;
    left: 632px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 590px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 480px;">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r1['aukciono_id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<script>
    $('.placiau').hover(function() {
        var aukciono_id = $(this).attr('data-aukciono-id');
        $('.aukciono_apzvalga[data-aukciono-id="'+aukciono_id+'"]').css('opacity', 1);
    }, function() {
        $('.aukciono_apzvalga').css('opacity', 0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) It works but I cannot unhover and it only shows 1 time.

Comment: I fixed it :) It should be `('.aukciono_apzvalga').css('opacity', 0);`.

Comment: Also, you did not insert `data-aukciono-id="<?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?>` in the `<td class="placiau">Plačiau <?php echo $r1['tai_aukciono_id']; ?></td>` but except this everything is ok :) Thank you very much! Please edit the answer, so other users will be able to it also :)

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis ok great

Comment: @Mogammad Something is bad with the while loop. It repeats every table and even if there are 20 table data, it shows only one. http://prntscr.com/fmd4hi

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis thats related to the query result, please share your db tables details and what is the expected result of each query

Comment: $aukciono_laimetojai_ir_aukciono_istorija_while - https://prnt.sc/fmdh81
$aukciono_istorija1_while - https://prnt.sc/fmdhqp

Comment: what is the relation between these two tables? or what your queries should do exactly?

Comment: First one should select all aukciono_ids where user_id is 206 and the second one should select all data in the tb_aukciono_istorija table where aukciono_ids are in the first one.

Comment: so if the user_id = 206, then select all data in the tb_aukciono_istorija where aukciono_id = 42, right ?

Comment: Yes, if a user hovers data-aukciono_id = 42